# In SQL , Instead of NULL values , I need to show user defined values

Tags: sql, null, zero

I don't know how to do this, Please anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try using `COALESCE()` ? ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on a select to modify null field to return something else

```
select COALESCE(t.[MyField],'This Field is NULL') from MyTable t
```

Link to functions for various rdbms : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

MS SQL Server for instance has ISNULL

Comment: that is true...

Answer (score 1):

If it is about changing the value in the database, try...

```sql
update mytable set myNullableAttribute = 'a specific value' where myNullableAttribute is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Kindnesscounts123YT ,

Please have a look below example for your question.

***In employee table ,before using ISNULL function it will show below Output***

**Query** :

```
select * from emp
```

**Output** :

empno   empname  salary gender
1       Pradeep   1500  Male
2       Ajay      2500  NULL

***When I use ISNULL function , i will get below output***

**Query :**

select
    empno,
    empname,
    salary,
    ISNULL(gender,'hi') as Gender
from 
    emp

**Output:**

empno  empname    salary  Gender
1       Pradeep 1500    Male
2       Ajay    2500    hi